# массовый insert

Tags: php

Есть переменная $search она содержит 0,44,77,22,113
Вторая переменная $del она содержит 33,66

Таблица

|  search |  del |

Как одним запросом сделать чтобы в этоге вишло так как на картинке ниже?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая база данных? MySQL?

Comment: Нужно реализовать это с помощью запроса или php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С начало генерируем запрос (готовый запрос будет помещен в переменную `$sql`)

```
$search = [0,44,77,22,113];
$del = [33,66];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO Table (search,del) VALUES ';
foreach ($search as $valueS){
    foreach ($del as $valueD){
        $sql.= "($valueS, $valueD),";
    }
}
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
//Отправка запроса
```

Осталось лишь отправить, способ отправки запроса уже зависит от вас.
Хочу отметить что данный код уязвим к SQL инъекциям, если же вы не фильтруете массивы `$search` и `$del`